# Matlabpool number of threads vs core

Tags: multithreading, matlab, multicore

I have a laptop running `Ubuntu` on `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz`. According to `Intel` website for the above processor (located [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/52224/Intel-Core-i5-2410M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz)), this processor has two cores and can run 4 threads at a time in parallel (because although it has 2 physical cores it has 4 logical cores).

When I start `matlabpool` it starts with `local` configuration and says it has connected to 2 labs. I suppose this means that it can run 2 threads in parallel. Does it not know that the CPU can actually run 4 threads in parallel?

Comment: If think my response answered the question, then please click the tick mark next to it. Otherwise, if you let me know in a comment what you find lacking, then I can attempt to improve it. Cheers.

Comment: @ColinTBowers: Done! Thanks for the answer and updating it with what you learnt from the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, the `local` configuration of `matlabpool` uses, by default, the number of physical cores a machine possesses, rather than the number of logical cores. Hence on your machine, `matlabpool` only connects to two labs.

However, this is just a setting and can be overwritten with the following command:

```
matlabpool poolsize n
```

where `n` is an integer between 1 and 12 denoting the number of labs you want Matlab to use.

Now we get to the interesting bit that I'm a bit better equipped to answer thanks to a quick lesson from @RodyOldenhuis in the comments.

Hyper-threading implies a given physical core can have two threads run through it at the same time. Of course, they can't literally be processed simultaneously. The idea goes more like this: If one of the threads is inefficient in allocating tasks to the core, then the core may exhibit some "down-time". A second thread can take advantage of this "down-time" to get some work done.

In my experience, Matlab is often efficient in its allocation of threads to cores, therefore with one Matlab thread (ie one lab) running through it, a core may have very little "down-time" and hence there will be very little advantage to hyper-threading. My desktop is a core-i7 with 4 physical cores but 8 logical cores. However, I notice very little difference between running a `parfor` loop with 4 labs versus 8 labs. In fact, 8 labs is often slower due to the start-up costs associated with initializing the extra labs.

Of course, this is probably all complicated by other external factors such as what other programs you might be running simultaneously to Matlab too.

In summary, my suspicion is that even though you could force Matlab to initialize 4 labs (or even 12 labs), you won't see much of a speed-up over 2 labs, since Matlab is generally fairly efficient at allocating tasks to the processor.

Comment: You still are limited by the number of physical cores. [Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is more like a more efficient scheduler for multi-threaded programs. Performance changes depend strongly on the type of process being run. For many algorithms there will be a significant improvement (max ~35% or so), for many others there will not be any noticeable change. In any case, having 4 physical cores *always* beats having 2 physical and 2 "fake" ones.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis In other words, if an algorithm is particularly efficient in the way it allocates a thread to a physical core, then there will be little benefit to hyper-threading. But if an algorithm allocates a thread in such a way that the core encounters "down-time", then a second thread allocated to the same core could take advantage of that "down-time" to get some work done. Is this a reasonable interpretation? ps thanks for the comment - if my interpretation is good, I'll update the answer.

Comment: As I understand it, yes, that is a good interpretation. There is more to it of course, but for the context of this question, this is good. There are more advantages than disadvantages to hyperthreading, so it's usually good to leave it on. But it really is a "poor man's multi-core", so don't expect HT to cut any algorithm's run time in half :)