# How to speed up this matlab code

Tags: performance, matlab

I have the following code:

```
Vector_LL = zeros(200,1);
for i = 1:200
    [Dummy, Vector_LL(i,1)] = posterior(GMMObj(i,1), Vector_Observation);
end
```

This part spent most of the time within my program, I would like to speed it up. I tried:

```
matlabpool;
Vector_LL = zeros(200,1);
parfor i = 1:200
    [Dummy, Vector_LL(i,1)] = posterior(GMMObj(i,1), Vector_Observation);
end
```

But the speed is even slower.
Anyone knows how to speed it up?

One more question, will it faster if I can convert the matlab build in function "posterior" into c++? I am not sure because the build in function should be optimized I belief ~"~

Comment: what is the size of `Vecor_Observation`

Comment: I meant what are its dimensions, is it row vector or col vector or a 2-d matrix ?

Comment: Possible suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468886/matlabpool-number-of-threads-vs-core

Comment: @Nishant it is a 1-by-50 vector

Comment: @CST-Link I have only 2 threads at most

Comment: I am not sure about this but give it a try
`[~ Vector_LL]  = posterior(GMMObj,repmat(Vector_Observation,200,1));`

Comment: @Nishant I cannot do that

Comment: Since you're not using the first output of posterior(), I think you actually want pdf(), e.g. Vector_LL(i,1) = log(pdf(GMMObj(1,i), Vector_Observation). Doesn't address the core problem, but may speed it up a little.

Comment: Thanks but it does not help much ~"~